# How to set the result code using setResult(); method

Tags: android

I am looking for an answer to the question that how can we give the result to the application which started my application.
I have reffered to many tutorials but they were useless...
Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manage start activity for result on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result); 
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Source: [How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result-on-android)

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Just some text");
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi there can you help me in one more topic i.e. setting the type of intent using setType()

Comment: Okay. `setType()` lets you specify the MIME type of the data that is contained in the intent. Plain text has a MIME type of `text/plain`. Have a look: http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/

Comment: Can you send me an example .... not a big one but just the matter in setType(____)

Comment: Suppose my intent uses the MIME type text/plain the how to define that using setType()  thats the question

Comment: I covered that in my example :)